# Использование домашнего сервера Mysql на хостинге

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, веб-сервер

На домашнем компьютере установил sql сервер и создал базу данных. Хочу ее подключить к вебстраничке котороя я расположил на вебхостинге. Можете помочь? При попытке внести данные в эту базу данных с помощью формы созданой на сайте выдает следующую ошибку: Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: 1045, ошибка: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) . Можете помочь?

Comment: А вы точно соединяетесь с той БД с которой хотите ? `'root'@'localhost'` намекает, что вы соединяетесь с БД запущенной на том же компе что и подключающийся скрипт. Т.е. скрипт соединяется с БД на самом хостинге где он находится.

Comment: В первом пераметре IP адрес машины с mysql сервером. Указанное имя пользователя должно позволять подключения с любых адресов на уровне прав доступа MySQL. И разумеется у машины с MySQL должен быть реальный ip или проброшенный порт 3306 и не закрытый фаерволом. И собственно сам MySQL сервер должен ожидать соединений на 0.0.0.0 а не 127.0.0.1

Comment: это я понимаю, но что писать в 
$mysql = new mysqli('aaa', 'user', 'pass, 'a_db');
что указывать здесь: aaa? имя моего домашнего компьютера, мои внешний IP, или чтонибудь еще?

Comment: спасибо, начну разбираться.

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко - то это невозможно и бессмысленно.

Единственным осмысленным вариантом действий будет

1. Сделать дамп базы данных, используя утилиту mysqldump
2. Узнать у провайдера параметры доступа к БД на хостинге
3. Залить дамп на хостинг и используя полученные параметры экспортировать его в БД хостинга
4. Подключить свой скрипт к БД хостинга

Comment: Почему невозможно то? Все можно, только вот насчет насчет смысла... В 99% и правда это бессмысленная идея